# difference between size_t (*B)[N] and size_t *B[N]

Tags: c++, g++

what's the difference between these two lines of code in c++?

`size_t (*B)[N] = new size_t[N][N];` and
`size_t *B[N] = new size_t[N][N];`

first one compiles correctly but with second line, g++ gives this error

```
matrixim.cpp:43:20: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
   43 |     size_t *B[N] = new size_t[N][N];
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) ..?

Comment: https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~ricko/rt_lt.rule.html

Answer (score 1):

```
size_t *B[N]
```

Here, `B` is an array of `N` pointers to `size_t`

```
size_t (*B)[N]
```

Here, `B` is a pointer to an array of `N` `size_t`s

---

Both of these constructs could be used to create something approximating a 2-dimensional array, but their layout in memory is very different.

`size_t *B[N]` would look something like this:

```
 B            +-------------+-------------+-----+-------------+
+--------+    | B[0][0]     | B[0][1]     | ... | B[0][N-1]   |
| B[0]   +--->+-------------+-------------+-----+-------------+
+--------+
| B[1]   +--->+-------------+-------------+-----+-------------+
+--------+    | B[1][0]     | B[1][1]     | ... | B[1][N-1]   |
|        |    +-------------+-------------+-----+-------------+
|  ...   |
|        |
+--------+
| B[N-1] +--->+-------------+-------------+-----+-------------+
+--------+    | B[N-1][0]   | B[N-1][1]   | ... | B[N-1][N-1] |
              +-------------+-------------+-----+-------------+
```

`B` is an array of `N` pointers to `size_t`, each of which points to the first element of an array of `N` `size_t`.

---

`size_t (*B)[N]` would look something like this:

```
 B        +---------------------------------------------------+
+----+    | B[0]                                              |
|    +--->+ +-------------+-------------+-----+-------------+ |
+----+    | | B[0][0]     | B[0][1]     | ... | B[0][N-1]   | |
          | +-------------+-------------+-----+-------------+ |
          +---------------------------------------------------+
          | B[1]                                              |
          | +-------------+-------------+-----+-------------+ |
          | | B[1][0]     | B[1][1]     | ... | B[1][N-1]   | |
          | +-------------+-------------+-----+-------------+ |
          +---------------------------------------------------+
          |                                                   |
          | ...                                               |
          |                                                   |
          +---------------------------------------------------+
          | B[N-1]                                            |
          | +-------------+-------------+-----+-------------+ |
          | | B[N-1][0]   | B[N-1][1]   | ... | B[N-1][N-1] | |
          | +-------------+-------------+-----+-------------+ |
          +---------------------------------------------------+
```

Here, `B` is a pointer to the first element of an array of `N` arrays of `N` `size_t`.